# result return in zend

Tags: zend-framework

I am writing query like this in zend but I am not getting  return result in controller file, then what I have to do for this.

```
    $result=$db->query("insert into geofences (`name`,`description`,`polygon`,  
                      `created_timestamp`,`company_id`)
                       values ('".$formData ['name']."',
                       '".$formData['description']."',  
                       GeomFromText('POLYGON(($polygon))'),
                       now(),'".$formData ['company_id']."')
                     ");

    return $result;
```

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean by " return result in controller file"? You want to have the result in a view script?

Comment: It is very unclear what is asked here! Try to add more information about the problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after a query() statment you have to fetch the results (if you have a SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE and EXPLAIN statement).... i think it uses the standard mysqli classes of PHP!
In your case (an insert statement) you have no result to fetch...i think (i'm not sure but i think this is the case) that it returns true on success and false if the query fails.

Look [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) and [here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.statement.html) for reference